# Electric eigen dependency

Tags: ros, opencv, eigen, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I successfully installed ros/electric in Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty) using

sudo apt-get install ros-electric-ros-base

However electric now uses eigen3 and it was not installed during electric installation (I earlier had eigen2 installed). Aptitude search shows following:

agadre@riverine:~$ aptitude search eigen

i   libeigen2-dev - lightweight C++ template library for linear algebra
p   libeigen2-doc - eigen2 API docmentation
p   libeigen3-dev - lightweight C++ template library for linear algebra
p   ros-electric-eigen - Eigen Library
p   ros-unstable-eigen - Eigen Library

Why was ros-electric-eigen (and by extension libeigen3-dev) not installed? Currently default eigen in Ubuntu 11.04 is libeigen2-dev.

This same question also extends to opencv-2.3.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11292/electric-eigen-dependency/) by [Aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1106/aditya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2011-09-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ros-electric-base does not come with opencv nor Eigen.  If you want opencv, install ros-electric-vision-opencv as well.

"ros-electric-eigen" is a backwards compatibility package; it mainly just forwards compile flags to the system dependency for eigen. The actual eigen3 library with electric is libeigen3-dev

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-09-23**:
libopencv2.3-dev is sufficient if you just are using OpenCV, but it does not provide ROS integration.

**Comment by [Aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1106/aditya/) on 2011-09-23**:
It seems that ros-electric-vision-opencv depends on geometry and orocos-kinematics-dynamics packages. Can I instead just install libopencv2.3-dev?